# Ubuntu not booting - Error "sulogin: cannot open password database"

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Ubuntu 12.04  is not booting up it shows a black screen with this error:

> sulogin: cannot open password database

I tried using the root console from the  recovery mode, but it shows the same error .
I also tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917124) method but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have corrupted your `/etc/passwd`

Try to boot a rescue system from the **ubuntu install cd** or **sysrescuecd** from cd or usb.
Then try to mount the root partition and inspect the `/etc/passwd`.

On normal systems the credentials are in the file `/etc/shadow`. 
Either disable this behavior with `shadowconfig off` or take care that both files are in sync.

Comment: I tried renaming the passwd file but it didn't helped. What should I do ?

Comment: Without`/etc/passwd` you are not able to log in.
You have to find the error inside the file.
As a workaround you can use the `/etc/passwd` from your rescue system.

Comment: Finally I got it to work.  I installed the ubuntu  in virtual machine and copied the passwd, shadow, gshadow and  group files from '/etc/' and pasted them in the ubuntu partition. ( I have a dual boot system win7 + ubuntu ) .  Thanks ! for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either root partition is corrupted, permission wrong on passwd, shadow, group

Necessary/Default system users are missing in passwd file.

In my case, default system users and root user were missing, hence systemd failed to start the service.